# External Content Types Office 365

Tags: external-content-type

I've the following:

In the cloud = SharePoint (office 365)

On-Premises = SQL DB's that I want to connect to from SharePoint

Is it possible to connect to my On-Premises SQL DB's?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah , You can connect SharePoint online to SQL DB.

You need to creating bridge between SQL DB And share point online cloud service.

Step 1: Prepare your external SQL data source to integrate with Office 365

step 2: Setup your SQL to SharePoint connection

Step 3: Manage your SQL data in the Office 365 SharePoint list

Refereed Link : You can get whole steps with screen  shot in below link.

[Connection between SharePoint online and SQL DB](http://www.layer2solutions.com/en/community/FAQs/cloud-connector/Pages/SQL-Sync-to-Office365.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so there is no way to do without a third party product?

Comment: I am not sure about that , But if You have a azure subscription than you will be able to get your. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alimaz/archive/2014/07/31/connect-sharepoint-online-to-an-on-premises-sql-server-from-an-azure-provider-hosted-app-using-hybrid-connections.aspx